# Deep Dream Generator

Tags: windows, gratis, offline, image-processing

I'm fascinated by Deep Dream pictures ([Gallery](https://deepdreamgenerator.com/#gallery)) and I'd love to create some on my own.

There have been a few online websites to upload pictures. Many of them do not work any more, but [Psychic VR Lab](http://psychic-vr-lab.com/deepdream/) seems to be up. However, I'd not like to upload photos into the Internet.

My PC is quite ok, water cooled and lots of RAM, so I hope that it would be capable enough to generate such pictures offline. However, it seems that the biggest problem is not generating images but setting up all the stuff needed to get it up and running.

There are websites which talk of "saves you 8 hours of setup headaches" ([source](https://github.com/ryankennedyio/deep-dream-generator)), but the question is, how many hours are left then? That site still needs a Docker environment, for which I need to register etc.

I'm looking for

- a deep dream picture generator
- that can be installed by any noob, e.g. using a simple `setup.exe`
- and that runs on Windows 10 (and 7 if possible, I'm still a 7 fan)
- that is gratis, not necessarily open-source

It would be great if it could learn from my own pictures, but generating some famous dog pictures from pre-learned models is ok, too.